# How to get all the Selected Cells in WPF datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, selection

I've a WPF datagrid, I want to get all the selected cells in the grid, I could do it by looping through all the items, so is there any built in way to do so?

I set two properties in DataGrid:

```
SelectionMode="Extended"   // for multiple selection

SelectionUnit="Cell"    //row should not be selected but cell should be
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DataGrid has [SelectedCells](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.selectedcells.aspx) property. Is it what you`re looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I know that `Grid.selecteditem` works for row select; I would think it should work on cells too.